# How to control sorting arrow indicator on QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

[image]

When this `QTableView` is created I want the sorting "arrow" indicator to be shown
on the column at the middle. The arrow needs to be pointing down. How to achieve this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = [[1, 'one', 'ONE'], [2, 'two', 'TWO'], [3, 'three', 'THREE']]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3 
    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return 

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

tableModel=Model()
tableView=QtGui.QTableView() 
tableView.setModel(tableModel)
tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)

tableView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [sortByColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#sortByColumn) function, using [Descending Order](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#SortOrder-enum) to make the arrow be "pointing down":

```
tableView.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)
```